# HornetQ store less meassages then max-queue-size

Tags: hornetq

HornetQ=2.2.14-Final

I have message with `10 bytes`;
I set max-queue-size to be `100 bytes`;
I expected to put 10 messages on the topic, but I successfully put less than 10

I understand that `hornetq` stores some metadata for each message and it affects the queue-size; Is this understanding correct?

How could I find the size of the metadata that `hornetq` stores for each message? 
Is it affected by the message size?
(I would like to calculate how many messages I can / could store)